# Crystal report printing extra letter "i" all over the report

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, c#-3.0, crystal-reports-2008

I have been facing this problem since ages now and finally decided to look for a solution to end this problem once and for all. Getting to the point.

I have created another crystal report but the problem is at runtime the crystal report displays extra letter "**i**" in the report as you can see in the below image.

[image: Image of the crystal report]

**Note** : This type of error does not appear in every PC and the font i am using for the **TextObject's** is **Calibri size:-10** and when i delete and insert a new TextObject with another font then it displays perfectly

Please tell me what should i do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is a known issue and seems like it can result in a conflict with usp10.dll:

http://scn.sap.com/thread/1820610

Suggestions here range from:

1. Use a different font - this seems to be specific to calibri.
2. Check you are using most up to date crystal DLLs on each machine.
3. Checking on each machine used what version of usp10.dll is used.

For what it's worth, if there is no real hangup on the font, you could probably change it and not very many people will notice...